# How to force child-div to "stretch" parent-flexbox (like img element does)?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a `flexbox` element with images that overflow and can be accessed via `horizontal scroll bar`:

```
<div class="flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll">
  <img class="rounded cursor-pointer" src="@/images/image.png" alt="meet-loaf image">
  <img class="rounded cursor-pointer" src="@/images/image.png" alt="meet-loaf image">
  <img class="rounded cursor-pointer" src="@/images/image.png" alt="meet-loaf image">
</div>
```

This happens because the `flexbox` div gets "stretched" by the `img` elements over the right edge and hidden by `overflow` prop.

[image]

Now I need to wrap the `img` elements into divs because I need to do an overlay with icons for each image. Problem is that the `flexbox` goes to `width: 100%` of its parent, as soon as the child elements are `div`s instead of `img`, preventing the overflow:

```
<div class="flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll">
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer" src="@/images/image.png" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer" src="@/images/image.png" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer" src="@/images/image.png" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

`img` elements have `display: inline` by default and I tried adding that to the `div` elements but it doesn't change anything. Any idea how to replicate above overflow behavior?

Comment: Did you simply forget to add the CSS ?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius no, I'm using `Tailwind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in tailwind, but it seems like in tailwind, `<img>` tag has default `max-width: 100%` that causes it to not have size bigger than a size that's determined by its parent (the `<div>` which width is determined by  parent's `flex`), to fix this, you only need to add `max-w-none` class to the images, like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex gap-2 overflow-x-scroll">
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer max-w-none" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x105" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer max-w-none" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x105" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer max-w-none" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x105" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
  <div><img class="rounded cursor-pointer max-w-none" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x105" alt="meet-loaf image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're absolute right about tailwind. In addition to `max-w-none`, I had to add `h-full` (`height: 100%`) to replicate desired overflow behaviour. Thank you!